# Rails 4: Search for Model WITHOUT a child that has an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

There has to be a better way to do this. Say I have:

```ruby
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :some_model
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag
  # Attributes:
  # - name:string
  # - is_bad:boolean
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :some_models, through: taggings
end
```

Some tags are bad, some are not.

I want a scope on SomeModel `scope :not_bad` such that I get any SomeModels that don't have any tags which are bad (is_bad == true).

At first glance:

```
SomeModel.joins(taggings: :tag).where('tags.is_bad = FALSE')
```

finds all **tagged** SomeModels without bad tags. Sure. But what about untagged SomeModels? They aren't bad...at least not yet. I need to try includes, to look for records which aren't tagged:

```
SomeModel.includes(taggings: :tag).where('tags.is_bad = FALSE')
```

Doesn't work, error. A look at the resulting SQL shows that I am not getting a join statement at all. I read some documentation and look at references, giving me:

```
SomeModel.includes(taggings: :tag).where('tags.is_bad = FALSE').references(taggings: :tag)
```

Which runs, but simply reproduces the output of joins...

At the moment I'm left with the functional, but terrible:

```
SomeModel.where.not(id: SomeModel.joins(taggings: :tag).where('tags.is_bad = TRUE').pluck(:id))
```

which requires multiple queries, and just feels horrid.

I know there has to be a good way to do this, what am I missing here?

Comment: `SomeModel.where.not(id: SomeModel.joins(taggings: :tag).where(tags: { is_bad: true }))`. If you remove `.pluck` and use a relation instead ActiveRecord can use it to construct a query with a subselect. However what you might want to do is construct a subquery which counts the associated records - how to best accomplish that depends on the DB.

Comment: Yep, that works. It still feels a bit ugly, but it does totally create just a single SQL query, and is a bit faster, so I can get behind it. I didn't actually know ActiveRecord did subqueries like that. Thanks mate.